# Testing with JEST and nock causing 'Cross origin null forbidden'

Tags: jestjs, nock

I'm trying to test my service with JEST and mocking endpoint with nock. Service looks like this

```
export async function get(id) {
    const params = {
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    let response = await fetch(`{$API}/projects/${id}`, params);

    return response.json();
}
```

Test:

```
import { 
  get 
} from './project';
import nock from 'nock';
const fetchNockProject = nock($API)
                          .get('/projects/1')
                          .reply('200', {});

      const data = await get(1);

      expect(data).resolves.toEqual(project);
```

When I run the test I get error:

*console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
      Error: Cross origin null forbidden*

*TypeError: Network request failed*

Any idea why virtual-console is throwing this as this is only service.

Answer (score 33):

I found a solution for my problem which was connected with CORS. Nock mock should be:

```
fetchNockProject = nock($API)
                   .defaultReplyHeaders({
                      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
                      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true' 
                    })
                   .get('/projects/1')
                   .reply('200', project);
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me !

Comment: You are a hero.

Comment: Is nock() a javascript function? Can you provide the link?

Comment: @Derzu nock is a library on npm

Answer (score 1):

Well, the posted answer didn't work for me and while I'm not saying it's wrong I thought I should share what **did work for me**.

In my case, my server is ASP.NET Core. I wasn't using the [Cors middleware module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1) that is provided. I added that in and configured it and that fixed my issue with no change to my javascript files.

Comment: The OP was mocking fetch(), and so it's also necessary to mock the "access-control-allow-origin" header. Since you're connecting to a real server, you want the server to send a real such header (which is what the CORS middleware does)